# Issue when injecting MavenProject into Maven test

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a Maven plugin test as outlined here:

http://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/getting-started/index.html

My Mojo injects this
    @Component
    private MavenProject project;

but `project.getBasedir()` returns the location of my plugin rather than my test pom.xml

Comment: Can you show your pom and your test code? (may be on github or something similar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with my test code.